# No module named 'watchdog.observers'; 'watchdog' is not a package

Tags: python, file-management, python-watchdog

I installed watchdog but trying to run any code doesn't work. I get that error message. Here's the code snippet. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Console Screenshot]

Comment: Although according to documentation it should work on python 2.x. But try updating to python 3.8. as I can import Watchdog in my environment (3.8.2).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, that's a very old and common issue when using Python packages. You named your file `watchdog.py` and the name of the package you use is `watchdog` too, so when you are trying to run `from watchdog.observers import ...` the interpreter would get confused and would try to import the current script itself.

Just rename the script to something else and everything should be all right.

Comment: Thank you. Never thought I'm this careless. :-*